# Highcharts 3D render problem on setState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am implementing react highchart 3d pie chart. Whenever I try to use `this.setState()` in lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`, the 3d chart displaces from it's position to right side diagonally. And if I remove `this.setState()` from componentDidMount(), it gets back to original position fine.

I am unable to fetch api call because of this odd behaviour as it is existing only in 3d pie charts. If I use 2d pie charts, `setState()` inside `componentDidMount()`, it works fine then.

This is how my problem goes:

```
App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official'
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';
highcharts3d(Highcharts);


export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
         test: 'testing state'
      }
    }

    componentDidMount(){  
      this.setState({
        test: 'changing state'
      })
    }
    render() {
        const options = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pie',
                options3d: {
                    enabled: true,
                    alpha: 45,
                    beta: 0
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    depth: 35,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.name}'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Browser share',
                data: [
                    ['Firefox', 45.0],
                    ['IE', 26.8],
                    {
                        name: 'Chrome',
                        y: 12.8,
                        sliced: true,
                        selected: true
                    },
                    ['Safari', 8.5],
                    ['Opera', 6.2],
                    ['Others', 0.7]
                ]
            }]
        }


        return (
            <div>
                <HighchartsReact 
                    options = {options}
                    highcharts={Highcharts} 

                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

before setState({})
[image: before setState({})]

after setState({})
[image]

Kindly help to resolve this odd bug .

Comment: Move the options constant outside your class or as a class property

Comment: @HMR Moving out of class worked. Can you explain the working behind this?

Comment: HighchartsReact won't re render when you set state because options didn't change. you can also try `<HighchartsReact key={new Date().getTime()} ` but that will hit performance. If you want to set options with setState you can set up codepen and I'll have a look to see what would work best.

Comment: @HMR Understood. But then how I am supposed to pass data from state into highcharts data series, if I were to take constant option outside the class?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/highcharts-react-demo-2bgxr?fontsize=14 This Is what I want to achieve, since I will be fetching the data dynamically from api into the charts soon.

Comment: Thank you for this question! Your two lines at the beginning `import highcharts3d from 'highcharts/highcharts-3d';
highcharts3d(Highcharts);` helped me enormously. My chart was not rendering in 3d and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Glad that it helped you out too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options are always 'new' for the wrapper if you keep them in the `render` method. That causes calling `chart.update()` with the same options. I have reproduced that situation here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mwv1kotb/

The best way is to keep options in a state: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      test: "testing state",
      chartOptions: {...}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      test: "changing state"
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          options={this.state.chartOptions}
          highcharts={Highcharts}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-om7n3

However, that problem looks like a bug, so I have reproduced it without React  and reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/11928

Comment: Following your demo, I tried to re-write my actual concern now. To pass the data from state to series data option after being updated in componentDidMount(). But data is not showing up. https://codesandbox.io/embed/highcharts-react-demo-2bgxr?fontsize=14

Comment: Hi @bubble-cord, You can update series data in this way: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-4mmvq